# How to pass a fragment to a message expression in Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

Is it possible to pass a fragment to a message expression in Thymeleaf? I want to re-use fragments for creating links in messages.

My fragment looks something like this:

```html
<div th:fragment="link(url, text)" th:remove="tag">
   <a th:href="@{${url}}"><span>${text}</span></a>
</div>
```

and I have a message like that:

```html
home.welcome=Hello User! See new content at {0}.
```

Now I want to pass the evaluated fragment to the message expression (pseudo-code):

```html
<p th:utext="#{home.welcome(${link:: link(url='myUrl', text='myText')})}"></p>
```

The resulting HTML should look like this:

```html
<p>
    Hello User! See new content at <a href="myUrl"><span>myText</span></a>.
</p>
```

I discovered [Fragment expressions](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/451) introduced in Thymeleaf 3 but I'm not sure if they are the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

You can try **th:with**.

Call fragments like so

```
<div th:include="fragments/common :: link" th:with="url='www.google.com', text='Click Me'"></div>
```

This is your fragment

```
<div th:fragment="link" th:remove="tag">
    <a th:href="@{${url}}"><span th:inline="text">[[${text}]]</span></a>
</div>
```

This is the HTML you will get

```
<div>
    <a href="www.google.com">
        <span>Click Me</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but this is not what I'm looking for. I know how to pass variables to fragments. I'm looking for a solution to pass the resulting HTML into a message expression.

Comment: I edited my question to better reflect these requirements